# Convertir un [object Object] en un array para implementar un ngFor en angular 11

Tags: array, angular, typescript, objeto, ngfor

Estoy tratando de mostrar los datos de una petición la cual me obtiene los datos de un id en especifico, el problema es que no se como hacer para que se convierta en un array interable ya que a lo que entiendo el problema es que no puede recorrer esa propiedad tipo object

servicio.ts el cual ya he implementado en otras peticiones me funciona de manera correcta solo lo adapte para recibir el parámetro del id

```
obtenerProvedor(_id:string){
  const url = `${base_url}/provider/get-provider/${_id}`;
  return this.http.get<getProvedor>(url,this.headers)
  .pipe(
    map(resp=>{
      const provedor=resp.provider
        console.log(provedor)
        return{
          
          provedor
        }
      
    })
  );
}
```

Código de component.ts

```
public provedor:Provedor[]=[];
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(({id})=>{
   this.cargarProvedor(id);
 })
     cargarProvedor(id:string){
    this.provedoresService.obtenerProvedor(id)
    .subscribe(resp=>{
    
      // this.provedor.push(provedor as unknown as Provedor)
      this.provedor=resp.provedor
     console.log("esta es la respuesta"+resp.provedor);
      console.log("Este es el provedor"+this.provedor)
    })
      }
```

Código de mi archivo model.ts

```
export interface getProvedor{
   
    provider:Provedor[];
}

export class Provedor {

   constructor(
       public _id: string,
       public name: string,
       public phone:number,
       public total:number,
       public status:boolean,
       public registerUser?: _provedorUser,
   ) { }
}
```

Por ultimo tengo los resultados de la consola donde imprimo el resultado del servicio el cual es exitoso, los resultados de mi componente y el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En angular existe un pipe que se llama [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) y puede ser de utilidad en estos casos:

```html
<div *ngFor="let par of objeto | keyvalue">
  <b>{{ par.key }}</b>:{{ par.value }}
</div>
```

Te dejo [un ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1bx6de?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Gracias, realizare las pruebas y te comento los resultados

Comment: Provando me muestra los datos pero no como esperaba igual voy a seguir tratando de adaptarlo a lo que requiero, tengo una duda mas hay alguna forma de pasar este objeto a un array?

Comment: Pues solo agrega corchetes a tu objeto y se volverá un array: `[miProveedor]`

Comment: encontre una nueva solución pero ahora tengo un problema, muestra los datos de manera correcta pero me repite html vacío, te dejo el link de la nueva pregunta por si tienes una solución colega https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497009/ngfor-no-funciona-de-manera-correcta muchas gracias ;)